# log commands by default/startup in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: logging, console, sublimetext3

I know that I can enable logging of commands in console by entering

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Is there some way to add this to the user preferences so that it is always enabled by default when I launch the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a setting for this in Sublime Text, no (though in Sublime Merge there is, since it has an output console but no method for entering commands at the current time).

In order to have this always available at startup you would need to implement a simple plugin that invokes it for you:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


def plugin_loaded():
    sublime.log_commands(True)
```

The easiest way to deploy this would be to use `Tools > Developer > New Plugin` from the menu and replace the stub code with the above, then save the result as a `.py` file in place Sublime will default to (your `User` package). Once you save the file you'll see the console say that it loaded it, and you're good to go.

The name you use for the file doesn't matter, so long as the extension is `.py` and that it's in the root of your `User` package (i.e. don't put it inside of a subdirectory in `User`, or it won't be considered a plugin).

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks!